# Can someone suggest a bitmap transformation class that isn't limited to affine transformations and takes advantage of any FP10 improvements?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm looking for a class that transforms bitmaps / textured polygons in Flash in 2D.  I want to be able to place the handles in arbitrary locations.  I've been using [this](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage) library for a few years but it just occured to me there may be an improved class taking advantage of some of the tricks in FP10/10.1.

Answer (score 2):

http://zehfernando.com/2010/the-best-drawplane-distortimage-method-ever/ is a pretty good article about the subject with regard to FP10, he provides his example and source; there are also some links at end of the article to a similar method called 'inverse homography' which was new to me... hopefully this can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen one, but I suppose it ought to be possible in theory. The trouble is that the new FP10 3D effects specifically apply 3D-like transforms, so it's true they aren't affine, but in order to get a bitmap into an arbitrary shape one must figure out the 3D rotation, depth of field and focal length which happen to achieve that shape.

The other problem is that the new FP10 transforms are also slower than the sort of thing the class you're using is doing, so all the 3D libraries you find are still doing affine tranforms under the hood. This will all change in a future player though - Adobe recently announced that they are working on new 3D APIs that will let you do polygon transforms on the GPU (arbitrary transforms, not 3D projections). So that's probably going to be the right time to start looking for a new transform class, in my opinion.

Info on new 3D APIs: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flash/molehill/